# Add mat-icons dynamically Angular 16

Tags: angular, typescript, dynamic, angular-material, frontend

I am creating a seating plan using the mat-grid-list component for creating some cells. I need that, once I clicked on a specific cell a mat icon appears, and when I click the same cell again it disappear.

I tried this. In my DOM:

```
<mat-grid-list [cols]="numColumns" id="container">
                <div *ngFor="let row of rows">
                    <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let col of cells" (click)="onCellClick($event)"
                        (dblclick)="onRename($event)" (contextmenu)="onRightClick($event)">
                        <mat-icon>{{icon}}</mat-icon>  
                    </mat-grid-tile>
                </div>
            </mat-grid-list>
```

In my Typescript, the onCellClick function is strucured this way:

```
  public icon!: string;
  /** Colors a cell depending on the selected icon */
  onCellClick(ev: any) {
    this.curr_cell = ev.target;
    if (this.regularSeatIconSelected === true) {
      this.curr_cell.value = 'Regular Seat';
      if (this.curr_cell.style.backgroundColor !== 'green') {
        this.curr_cell.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
        this.icon = 'event_seat';
      } else {
        this.curr_cell.style.backgroundColor = '';
        this.curr_cell.value = '';
        this.icon = '';
      }
    }
```

The problem with this code, is that when i click on a cell, every cell in the grid-list is updated with this new icon.
How can i add the icon for a specific cell?
If you have any suggestion please let me know.
Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a 2d Array of values, and maintain a local property called `selected` in each of the elements, but for simplicity purposes, please find below the code, that will toggle the class through javascript. Ideally you should use the first option.

```
import { Component, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { MatGridTile, MatIcon } from '@angular/material';

/**
 * @title Basic icons
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'icon-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'icon-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['icon-overview-example.css'],
})
export class IconOverviewExample {
  numColumns = 5;
  rows = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  cells = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  regularSeatIconSelected = true;

  onCellClick(ev: any) {
    console.log(ev.target);
    const curr_cell = ev.target.classList.contains('mat-icon')
      ? ev.target.parentElement
      : ev.target;
      const icon = ev.target.querySelector('.mat-icon') || ev.target;
    console.log(curr_cell);
    if (this.regularSeatIconSelected) {
      curr_cell.value = 'Regular Seat';
      if (curr_cell.style.backgroundColor !== 'green') {
        curr_cell.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
        icon.innerText = 'event_seat';
      } else {
        curr_cell.style.backgroundColor = '';
        curr_cell.value = '';
        icon.innerText = '';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-icons-pt3fwt)